# Parsing mathematical expression from sentence (string) Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a task where I should be parsing mathematical expressions from sentence string.

I know that every variable in math expression starts with $.

Operators that are allowed in these expressions are:

- >
- <
- -
- +
- *
- /

String could be for example:

- "How much is $a * $b"
- "Car goes $a / $b km/h"
- "How much is $a + 2 * $b"

Any idea how I should approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/(?:\$\w+|\d+) ?(?:km\/h)?[><+*/-] ?(?: ?(?:\$\w+|\d+) ?(?:km\/h)?[><+*/-]?)*/
```

I use `?:` for non-capturing groups.

For test and extended comments see: https://regex101.com/

Comment: The km/h part was not supposed to be part of the equation, but I got it working by removing that part of the regex. Thank you very much. I'll have to learn more about regular expressions. :)